# How to know whether SSO is enabled for current user?

Tags: apex, single-sign-on, user

I am trying to reset password for users. My requirement is : When I create user through code(where input is grabbed through custom UI form), a mail should be triggered, to user which contains a link to reset the password.

However, everything went smooth, I tried and able to do this with :

```
System.ResetPasswordResult rstPSWRDrs = system.resetPassword(userTempObj.Id, true);
```

When, I browsed through web, I found that I can't reset password for SSO enabled users. Link -> [Link to Document](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005229&language=en_US)

So, alternate workaround, I know 2 option:

1. Clicking RESET password mannualy, on USER page.
2. Finding the reason,
   which enables SSO for particular user, I will not insert this, for
   that user, and after sending reset link, I will update that.

I tried with FederationId of user, while trying option 2. But no luck!!! 
Please let me know, if you have any workaround/hack for that. 
Thanks!

Comment: if Profile has single signon enabled and user has federationId - does that not work?  Secondary use case would be a Permission Set with single signon enabled + federation Id

Comment: @cropredy looks like we can minimize problem to finding relation bitween Profile and ConnectedApplication.

Comment: @cropredy here is what I have found https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm

Comment: Thanks @cropredy for the hint. I got two fields on profile, which decides, whether the user is SSO is enabled or not.
1. IsSSoEnabled
2. PermissionsIsSsoEnabled